# How to call edit-and-execute-command from script/manually or pipe to it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

When you type 'v' (or ctrl x ctrl e in emacs mode) you get an editor with a blank tmp file and upon close+save the content is executed.

What is the command that is called from this keybind that could be used to pipe to or call from a script? 
Alternatively can you somehow pipe a string to fc rather than bash history?

I tried various ways of edit-and-execute-command, of piping to fc and so on but I'm at a loss...

A workaround would be putting an echo in front, execute it so it's in bash history, then call fc on last command and edit out the echo but that's awful

Another would be to write a script to do just that but I'd like to know if it's possible to do "out of the box' first

Comment: Does `set -v` help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What bash is doing is roughly equivalent to:

```sh
file=$(mktemp); 
$EDITOR $file; 
source $file; 
unlink $file;
```